# Java built-in Adjacency List

Tags: java, graph, java-8, adjacency-list, sun

I was reading this [which consists of old java packages](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?package=sun.security.provider) such as sun packages. I find some of them useful.

On of them is `sun.security.provider.certpath.Vertex`, which represents a [Vertex](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=sun.security.provider.certpath.Vertex) and following the Vertex class was AdjacencyList i.e `sun.security.provider.certpath.AdjacencyList`, which represents the adjacency list of vertexes.

From [the documentation says](http://www.logmethods.com/cview/java/JRE%20classes/sun/security/provider/certpath/AdjacencyList.java),

> An AdjacencyList is used to store the history of certification paths.

Is this specifically defined for the X500 certificates and their paths and ignore the internal API warning that cannot be suppressed? Can we use this classes for the generic graphs for problem solving on JDK 1.8?

Comment: You shouldn't use classes from the `sun.*` packages, they are implementation details of Java and could change without notice (or they might not even exist in alternative implementations of Java).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That class is a specialised, non-generic implementation hard-coded to work with certificate validation steps. You cannot use it for other things.